# Installing Ubuntu Server 18.10

Tags: server

I'm installing Ubuntu Server on my PC. But I have some recovery drives on the disk that where I will install Ubuntu server. 
Is there away to install ubuntu server which will not overwrite the entire disk and only use the partition that I created for it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select the partition you want if you manually configure partition in your setup

Keep in mind that you'll have to basically partition the partition for /home, /, /boot, etc. Make sure you have the room on your disk, and partition it carefully or you'll lose everything

Easier solution is to use an USB drive for recovery, but since you didn't present that as an option for you, I'll assume it isn't